# what is the difference between /login?redirect=%2F and /login?Local environment both are working but after i depoloy on server /login is not work

Tags: authentication

this is my auth config in nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
      fetchUserOnLogin: false,
      resetOnError: false,
      watchLoggedIn: true,
      strategies: {
        local: {
          endpoints: {
            login: { url: '/auth/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
            logout: { url: '/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
            user: { url: '/auth/user', method: 'get', propertyName: 'data' }
          },
          redirect: {
            login: '/login',
            home: '/'
          },
          token: {
            type: 'Bearer',
            name: 'auth._token.local'
          },
          cookie: {
            name: 'auth._token.local',
            options: {
              path: '/'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

On server the login mutation is taking too long to get response and the server is crahsed. I just want to know why it is happened and how can i fix this error.
When i try with this /login?redirect=%2F  route on server the login mutaion is working normally and when i try with /login the mutation is not working.
Please help me.